# Eigenvector proprieties of special diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have a matrix $A$ given by

\begin{equation}
a_{ij} = \alpha \, \exp\left (\frac{-d_{ij}^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
\end{equation}
where d is the distance between each element in the matrix

So, A is symmetric and also has a special decaying propriety.
Is there anything we can say about the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of this matrix?

I know that A is diagonalizable, and the eigenvectors are orthogonal. Is something more to it?
Example of a 4x4 structure

```
1.0000    0.6065    0.6065    0.3679
0.6065    1.0000    0.3679    0.6065
0.6065    0.3679    1.0000    0.6065
0.3679    0.6065    0.6065    1.0000
```

Comment: The properties of the “RBF kernel” ensure that your matrix will have non-negative eigenvalues